# How can I change the Microsoft Dynamic 365 X++ class template in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, axapta, x++, suppress-warnings, dynamics-365-operations

I've currently set up a environment for learning Microsoft Dynamics 365.
While I am playing around with code, I am getting a million warnings about missing documentation.

As:

1. I am a strong believer in "[Clean Code](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Robert-Martin/dp/0132350882)"; and
2. I especially don't want to document all these things while just messing about to learn; and
3. I want visibility of other warnings which may be more important or at least interesting; and
4. I prefer explicit code.

I want to suppress all the warnings and always include the "public" keyword by default for all my classes.

So, I want to change the template from:

```
class AssetConsistencyCheck
{
}
```

to

```
[SuppressBPWarning("BPXmlDocNoDocumentationComments", "Prefer clean code!")]
public class AssetConsistencyCheck
{
}
```

Is this possible, and if so how?

Comment: You could create a code snippet, see for example http://kashperuk.blogspot.com/2016/09/development-tools-editor-scripts-in.html

Comment: You can disable best practices (BP's) such as the need for documentation on a per model basis. Setup is found in Visual Studio under `menu Dynamics 365 > Options... > Best practices` > select your model in the top right drop down > uncheck the relevant documentation BP rules under `Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Framework.CodeStyleRules > XmlDocumentationRules`.

Comment: @Sander , I tried unchecking the rules, but it did not seem to work.  Anyway, I still want to know how to create a template.  ;-)